# How to output symbol in Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, x86, output, dos, fasm

I'm new to assembly language and based on my understanding to perform a task there is a specific combination of interupt and mov (ex. int21h/ah=39h is for making directory). What I wan't to know is how do you output '#' with a specific color and how many of them is to be printed out instead of doing it 1 by 1, also what is next line in assembly language? we need to make an image using '#' symbol. thanks

Comment: Presumably you have a function list, use it! If not, get one! You might be interested in int21/02, int21/09, int10/09 and int10/13

Comment: Ralf Brown's interrupt list http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output a number of identical characters having a certain color use video BIOS function 09h.

```
                             Example
mov cx, ...    ;count         6 = '######'
mov bh, 0
mov bl, ...    ;color         1Eh = Yellow on Blue
mov ah, 09h
mov al, ...    ;character     '#'
int 10h
```

*next line* means that you output a carriage return and a linefeed. For this you use another video BIOS function 0Eh.

```
mov bx,0007h
mov ax,0E0Dh   ;0Dh = carriage return
int 10h
mov ax,0E0Ah   ;0Ah = linefeed
int 10h
```